# Manage loops outside it

Tags: loops, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I want to run a loop that takes pictures. I want to run the loop when the client wants and stop it whenever the video needs to stop been recorded (all images would be put together into a video). If i run the loop, I cant do anything till it stops, so i have no way no know. I dont want either to set a specific time nor to ask the client if he wants to take the next photogram, because it would get the images with delay and it would also be annoying to type 60 times yes to record a 1 sec video. If i can do a frontend call and the loops running in the backend, it would be amazing. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want to use either the `multiprocessing` module (https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html) or the `threading` module (https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html).

Comment: @dano and whats the difference? It says they are very similar

Comment: `threading` lets your create and manage threads, which is a sequence of execution within a single process. So, you would have one process with two threads running at once; one thread would be taking pictures, the other would be waiting for user input that can alert the picture-taking thread to stop. `multiprocessing` essentially does the same thing, but uses separate processes to create separate sequences of execution, instead of threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't claim perfection, but this can be modified to your use:

```
import thread

try:
    from msvcrt import getch
except ImportError:
    def getch():
        import sys, tty, termios
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch

char = None
def keypress():
    global char
    char = getch()

thread.start_new_thread(keypress, ())

i=1
while True:
    if char is not None:
        print "Key pressed is {} -- exiting loop".format(char)
        break
    print "Loop has run {} times".format(i)
    i+=1
```

Comment: Because I need to :-)   Joking aside, I modified with no sleep statement... Just a demo.

Comment: it shows: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/juan/Documents/eg.py", line 21, in keypress
    char = getch()
  File "/Users/juan/Documents/eg.py", line 7, in getch
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks, python 2.7.6, but don't worry too much, I've found another way using this, I took the literal getch class with mac os x implementation